# Audio and Video not playing in Android WebView HTML5

Tags: android, html, android-webview, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm unable to play the Audio and Video from the Android WebView whenever this web page is opened in it. Both the links are HTML5 supported. WebView is not working properly to play Audio and Video.

Example Web Page Link for:

Audio - https://kulturpunkt.org/owner/49/group/175/record/3550

Video - https://kulturpunkt.org/owner/49/group/175/record/3285

Solutions Tried:

> **1.** Earlier, the Audio and Video links were not secure (https), we now **changed it to secure link (https)**. This was done based on below errors

Error for Audio: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSvqA.png)

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(13)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://kulturpunkt.org/owner/49/group/175/record/3550' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'http://mm.dimu.org/multimedia/032wX1jg2tKY.mp3?mmid=032wX1jg2tKY&a=none'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.", source: https://kulturpunkt.org/assets/kp.footer.2.0.19.js (13)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.", source: https://kulturpunkt.org/owner/49/group/175/record/3550 (0)
```

Error for Video: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmVKx.png)

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(13)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://kulturpunkt.org/owner/49/group/175/record/3285' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'http://mm.dimu.org/multimedia/012wWXC2dbyh.mp4?mmid=012wWXC2dbyh&a=none'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.", source: https://kulturpunkt.org/assets/kp.footer.2.0.19.js 
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.", source: https://kulturpunkt.org/owner/49/group/175/record/3550 (0)
```

> **2.** Second, I reduced the size of the Audio and Video to **7.33MB** and **25.6MB** as I thought Size might not be allowing the media to load properly and play in the WebView.
>
> **3.** Finally, we tried to change the **codecs** of the Audio and Video to the **supported formats** by the Android WebView.
>
> **4.** The **Android System WebView** app is also updated from Play Store in the device with OS Android 6.0 (M). `App Version - 55.0.2883.91 (09 Dec 2016)`

I tried testing it in all different devices with different OS but the Android WebView behavior remains the same.

I don't understand what exactly is the issue here. How can I resolve this issue?

> I cannot use **[JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)** as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16211546/1576416), Even though, I have control over the server changes and the app changes. I want to implement it with default behavior of WebView.

Below is the code for my WebView:

```
inAppWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.in_app_web_view);
inAppWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
inAppWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            inAppWebView.loadUrl(webURL);
            return true;
        }

        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            loadProgressDialog(InAppWebViewActivity.this);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
inAppWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
inAppWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
inAppWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
inAppWebView.loadUrl(webURL);
```

Any suggestions or references will be helpful.

Comment: did you find any work around for this @amrut ?

Comment: @Shubhral - nothing found yet

Comment: did u have any workarounds for this?

Comment: (I only have issues with missing Audio, video works). Any updates? We used the version 50 of the WebView and Audio works but as soon as we go higher it stops. (but the lower version have different issues with CSS 100% height etc.). Looking forward to any info!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Manifest file.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

and this after the creation of your webview

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( 
        WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
}
```